Understanding the logic of ADMM for a multi-agent/consensus optimization
I have an ILP that consists of 3 binary decision variables: $x_1, x_2, x_3 \in {0,1}$. The system consists of N agents, each wanting to make their own decision for variables $x_2$ and $x_3$, while all agents must agree on the variables of $x_1$. The aim is maximize a linear gain that is associated with each variable. The problem is formulated as follows:
$max. \sum_{i}\sum_{j}g_{i,j}^1 x_{i,j}^1 + \frac{1}{N}\sum_{n}\Big(\sum_{i}\sum_{j}g_{i,j,n}^2 x_{i,j,n}^2 + \sum_{i}\sum_{j}g_{i,j,n}^3 x_{i,j,n}^3\Big) \\
s.t. x_{i,j,n}^2 + x_{i,j,n}^3 \leq 1, \forall i, \forall j, \forall n \\
\quad x_{i,j,n}^3 - x_{i,j}^1 \leq 0, \forall i, \forall j, \forall n$
The problem also includes some other knapsack constraints on $x_1, x_2, x_3$ that I will leave out for brevity.
My questions are:

Since each agent can make their own decision on $x_2$ and $x_3$ but all agents must have the same $x_1$, can I use consensus ADMM to solve large-scale instances of this problem?

Is the logic behind consensus ADMM to solve the "copy" of the problem at each agent, and gradually penalize the solutions that are far from "consensus" until its reached? Does this mean that when the problem has a large number of consensus variables (i.e., $x_1$), we are making an equal number of copies? Wouldn't that be counterintuitive when we're trying to simplify the solution procedure?


P.S.: I am very new to ADMM and optimization so please bear with me.

Consensus ADMM under certain regularity conditions can give you the optimal solution for convex optimization problems. I do not believe the method can provide such a guarantee for general ILPs.
